# index error in py2neo , Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I'm brandnew to py2neo so I figured I would start off with a simple program. Its returning a TypeError: Index is not iterable. Anyway I'm trying to add a set of nodes and then create relationships for them while avoiding duplicates. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
from py2neo import neo4j, cypher
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")

happy = "happy"
glad = "glad"
mad = "mad"
irate = "irate"
love = "love"

wordindex = graph_db.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "word")

for node in wordindex:
              wordindex.add("word", node["word"], node)


def createnodes(a, b, c, d, e):
nodes = wordindex.get_or_create(
    {"word": (a)},
    {"word": (b)},
    {"word": (c)},
    {"word": (d)},
    {"word": (e)},
    )

def createrel(a, b, c, d, e):
rels = wordindex.get_or_create(
    ((a), "is", (b)),
    ((c), "is", (d)),
    ((e), "is", (a)),
    )


createnodes(happy, glad, mad, irate, love)
createrel(happy, glad, mad, irate, love)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used a number of methods here incorrectly, beginning with the [`Index.add`](http://nigelsmall.com/_api/py2neo/neo4j.html#py2neo.neo4j.Index.add) method. This method should be used to add an existing node into an index but at this point in the code no nodes have actually been created. I think that you instead want to use [`Index.get_or_create`](http://nigelsmall.com/_api/py2neo/neo4j.html#py2neo.neo4j.Index.get_or_create) as follows:

```
nodes = []
for word in [happy, glad, mad, irate, love]:
    # get or create an entry in wordindex and append it to the `nodes` list
    nodes.append(wordindex.get_or_create("word", word, {"word": word}))
```

This essentially then replaces your `createnodes` function as the nodes are created directly through the index, maintaining uniqueness.

You can then uniquely create your relationships with the node objects obtained by the code above, plus the [`GraphDatabaseService.get_or_create_relationships`](http://nigelsmall.com/_api/py2neo/neo4j.html#py2neo.neo4j.GraphDatabaseService.get_or_create_relationships) method as follows:

```
graph_db.get_or_create_relationships(
    (nodes[0], "is", nodes[1]),
    (nodes[2], "is", nodes[3]),
    (nodes[4], "is", nodes[0]),
)
```

Hope this helps

Nigel

Comment: thanks Nigel, very helpful! I've also found your presentation on slideshare very useful as well